# Shutdown prompt keeps popping up

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, shutdown, cinema-display

I have a weird problem. Recently, I have noticed whenever I connect my MacBook Pro to my screen, the shutdown prompt (see picture) pops up and no matter how many times I click on "Cancel" it keeps popping up. It even steals the screen attention (that window gets highlighted) meaning that I'm not able to do anything at all.
Usually, it stops after a while (like 10 minutes or more), but it is nondeterministic.

I have a theory about what can be the cause. The screen I have is one of these old Apple Cinema displays (maybe ten years old), and it has a power button (touch-based) on it. I think it must be related to this. Somehow it feels as if the button is continuously getting pressed. In the Display preferences, there is an option related to the button. It's already set to "Does nothing" but the problem still occurs. I tried changing it to "Turns the display on and off", and the display started blinking, constantly turning on and off, which proves my hypothesis is correct. However, I have no idea what this is happening and how I can stop it.

Any ideas?

[image: shutdown prompt]
[image: display options]

Comment: Can you specify the exact models of MacBook Pro and Cinema Display you're using?

Comment: The display is an old 30" Apple Cinema HD Display (A1083 or M9179LL/A) and the Macbook is an early-2015 MacBook Pro.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Cinema_Display
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp715?locale=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might your keyboard issue which is just a random guess. However before going on hardware, why not you try to **reset SMC**.

The System Management Controller — or SMC — is responsible for various pieces of hardware inside your machines such as the battery, fans, logic board and more.

- The SMC is even responsible for recognizing when certain buttons are
  pressed.

You can take the guidance from **https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295**

It doesn't hamper anything so I think it is worth to try.

Comment: Resetting SMC seems to have resolved the issue. I haven't experienced the issue after the reset yet.